# Should an accent be used in apróximadamente?

Tags: ortografía, acentuación

My Spanish textbook (Spanish Cat level 1) has "apróximadamente" in the following context:

> El norte de Chile tiene muy buen clima, no hay muchas lluvias pero la
>   temperatura no varia mucho, es de apróximadamente 20°C. En el sur es frío y llueve en invierno. En Santiago, el invierno puede ser de -2°C.

If I look up [spanishdict](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/apr%C3%B3ximadamente) it only has an entry for the form without an accent, and the examples (at least for the [first page](http://www.spanishdict.com/examples/aproximadamente)) for aproximadamente seem to only be without an accent. Diccionario de la lengua española doesn't have the version with an accent. However, the English edition of [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apr%C3%B3ximadamente) regards the form with an accent as legitimate.

Should an accent be used in apróximadamente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it should not.

*Aproximadamente* is formed off of *aproximada*, which does not use an accent. The stress is on the next to the last *a* (aproxiMAda) and that syllable maintains the stress with *-mente* (aproxiMAdaMENte).